# Send email notification when Firebase Real Time Database updates

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

New to firebase and somewhat new to javascript. I want to send an email notification when a form on my static page is submitted to the firebase real-time database. Notification email will have the information submitted.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at one of the official Firebase samples for Cloud Functions:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation

This samples "shows how to send a confirmation emails to users who are subscribing/un-subscribing to a newsletter". It is triggered when a user write some data under as specific Real Time Database node. So it is very similar to your case: when "a form on my static page is submitted to the firebase real-time database" it will write under a DB node.

You can also adapt it in order to use Sengrid, with their library for node.js https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs. It works very well and is also a recommended solution by Firebase.

In case you encounter difficulties when adapting this sample to your case, do not hesitate to share your code and ask for help.

Comment: The updated Firebase sample link: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/email-confirmation